# Time aggregate across years in R

Tags: r, aggregate

I have 10 years of daily precipitation data. I'm trying to get the total precipitation that occurs between, for exemple, december and april of the following year. **Another complication is that the period can change, say Dec-15 to March-15**

I know how to do this using `aggregate` or `group_by` if I don't have to go across years. But I'm completely out of ideas how to solve this year crossing problem.

Here is a code example of what I'm trying to get.

```r
library(lubridate)

precip <- data.frame(d = seq.Date(from = as.Date('2001-01-01'),
                                  to = as.Date('2004-12-31'),
                                  by = 'day'),
                     prec = runif(1461))

precip$y <- year(precip$d)
precip$m <- month(precip$d)

# I can aggregate by year
aggregate(precip$prec, by = list(precip$y), sum)

# I can aggregate by year, month
aggregate(precip$prec, by = list(precip$y, precip$m), sum)

# How can I aggregate by a period that crosses between years?
# my desired output would be something like
# Group.1        x
# 1 2001-12-15 to 2002-03-15 184.4885
# 2 2002-12-15 to 2003-03-15 192.8315
# 3 2003-12-15 to 2004-03-15 178.8507
```

I don't need the group name to contain the period as a string. It could be just an index.

Comment: It would be easier to help if you make this question specific rather than keeping it general. Include sample data and show the expected output for it.

Comment: echo Ronak. Whats your data.frame look like? Will simple indexing not work?

Comment: Added a code example

Answer (score 1):

The question was later updated to ask for seasons that are not whole months so this is an update to the original answer to address that.  It uses the input in the Note at the end and the start date and end date of a prototype season.  If the season spans the end of February be sure to choose a leap year (such as the year 2000 as shown in the example below).

We create a sequence of all dates from the start date to the end date called template.  Convert that to a character vector of all possible month/days in the season, mmdd.

Next define in_season which has one element per row of precip and is TRUE if the month and day of that row match any month and day in the template.

Then define season_no which has one element per row of precip identifying each season with a unique number.  The number is 0 for rows whose date is not in season and is otherwise an increasing positive number.

Subset the data to the in season rows and calculate the least and greatest date in each season giving precip0.

Finally aggregate prec by the start/end dates and also use aggregate to find how many days are in each of the seasons.  This will include partial seasons if they exist.  If this is not wanted subset the data first or subset the result as in the commented out line in the code.

No packages are used.

```
# to change definition of season change next 2 lines
start_template <- as.Date("1999-12-15")
end_template <- as.Date("2000-03-15")  # note that year 2000 incl Feb 29

# mmdd character vector contains the mm-dd values in season
template <- seq(start_template, end_template, "day")
mmdd <- format(template, "%m-%d")

in_season <- format(precip$d, "%m-%d") %in% mmdd
season_no <- with(rle(in_season), rep(seq_along(lengths), lengths)) * in_season

precip0 <- transform(subset(cbind(precip, season_no), in_season),
  start_date = ave(d, season_no, FUN = min),
  end_date = ave(d, season_no, FUN = max))

ag <- aggregate(cbind(days = 1, prec) ~ start_date + end_date, precip0, sum)

# uncomment if partial seasons not wanted
# ag <- subset(ag, days >= length(mmdd) - 1)
```

giving:

```
> ag
  start_date   end_date days      prec
2 2001-01-01 2001-03-15   74 37.963828
3 2001-12-15 2002-03-15   91 44.543114
4 2002-12-15 2003-03-15   91 43.182177
5 2003-12-15 2004-03-15   92 44.083236
1 2004-12-15 2004-12-31   17  9.180353
```

### Original answer assuming whole months

The inputs are precip (given in the Note at the end and season which is a vector of month numbers (Jan=1, Feb=2, ..., Dec=12) in order that they appear within the season.  In the example below we use c(12, 1:3), i.e. Dec - Mar.

The code below uses precip and season to set the following variables:

- last_month is the month number of the last month in the season
- ym is a yearmon class vector with corresponding year/months.  Internally it is represented as a year plus 0 for Jan, 1/12 for Feb, ..., 11/12 for Dec.  ym is the same length as x.
- cross is a logical scalar that is TRUE if the season crosses a year boundary and otherwise FALSE
- in_season is TRUE if the corresponding date is within the season.  in_season is the same length as x.
- start_year and end_year are the corresponding years for the start and end of the season if the date is in season or 0 if not in season.  start_year and end_year are each the same length as x.
- start_date and end_date are the corresponding season start and end dates

We then insert start_year and end_year and subset to those rows for which season is TRUE.  Finally we aggregate by start_year and end_year.

```
library(zoo)

# define season as Dec - Mar
season <- c(12, 1:3)  # month numbers in order they appear in season

last_month <- tail(season, 1)
ym <- as.yearmon(precip$d)
cross <- last_month < season[1]
in_season <- cycle(ym) %in% season

start_year <- as.integer(ym - cross * last_month / 12) * in_season
end_year <- start_year + cross * in_season

start_date <- as.Date(paste(start_year, season[1], 1, sep = "-"))
end_date <- as.Date(as.yearmon(paste(end_year, last_month, sep = "-")), frac = 1)

precip0 <- subset(data.frame(start_date, end_date, precip), in_season)
aggregate(prec ~ start_date + end_date, precip0, sum)
```

giving:

```
  start_date   end_date     prec
1 2000-12-01 2001-03-31 45.70959
2 2001-12-01 2002-03-31 58.67224
3 2002-12-01 2003-03-31 57.93712
4 2003-12-01 2004-03-31 59.66424
5 2004-12-01 2005-03-31 16.69944
```

or perhaps use start_year and end_year since then we can readily plot prec vs. end_year, say.

```
precip0 <- subset(data.frame(start_year, end_year, precip), in_season)
aggregate(prec ~ start_year + end_year, precip0, sum)
```

### Note

We assume that the input precip is the following.  This is the same as in the question except we have added set.seed to make it reproducible.

```
set.seed(123)
precip <- data.frame(d = seq.Date(from = as.Date('2001-01-01'),
                                  to = as.Date('2004-12-31'),
                                  by = 'day'),
                     prec = runif(1461))
```

Comment: Wow! This is great. I'm just sorry I was not clear enough in my example. My periods needs to be defined at a 'finer time scale'. For instance, how to agregate for all Dec 15th to March15th for every year? I'll update the question in order to make it clearer. An meanwhile, I'll also try to build upon your great answer to get my desired output

Comment: Have added another solution to address daily granularity.

Answer (score 0):

I believed I solved it using `cut`. This way I can set arbitrary start and end dates, as long as they are not in the same month. That's because I'm using the start month as filter to trow away off season observations.

I'm not sure it's the most foolproof or elegant solution. But...

```r
startDate <- as.Date('2003-12-01')
endDate <- as.Date('2004-04-01')

start_month <- month(startDate)
start_day <- day(startDate)

end_month <- month(endDate)
end_day <- day(endDate)

start_year <- min(year(precip$d))
end_year <- max(year(precip$d))

breaks <- lapply(start_year:end_year, function (x) {
  c(paste (x, start_month, start_day), paste ( x + 1, end_month, end_day))
})

breaks <- unlist(breaks)

precip$season <- cut(precip$d, ymd(breaks))

precip0 <- precip[month(ymd(precip$season)) == start_month,]

aggregate(prec ~ season, precip0, sum)
```

This results in

```r
      season     prec
1 2001-12-01 58.67224
2 2002-12-01 57.93712
3 2003-12-01 59.66424
4 2004-12-01 16.69944
```